# About Paper and Ink in material design

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

> "Now why is this asymmetry important ? Well it helps the user understand the difference between something that’s resizing and staying in that place, and something that’s moving within z.
>
> If I move within z, that’s kind of the same as symmetric scale, as you get closer is growing in both aspects at the same rate. By doing re-sizes asymmetrically, we’re letting the user know OK, that content is actually staying up at the same z level. The movement is a different signal to them."

(from [Video Paper and Ink : The Materials that Matter](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html))

What does the above description mean ?

Could someone explain it ?

Comment: Did that answer your question? If not let me know what you still have a question on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

If you resize along the x and the y axis simultaneously, it would appear that the paper is moving closer to you, instead of just growing in size.

---

To go into detail:

When something moves along a "z" axis, the height of that object is increasing the distance between itself, and the arbitrary surface to which we have assigned as being the reference surface point.

For example, take a blank piece of paper and lay it on your desk. Raising the paper up and down would be moving it along the "z" axis.

That is one of the main theories behind material design. The elements are pieces of paper, which are drawn on with ink (as previously described in the same video). The surface that those pieces of paper "rest" on is bottom of the phone, and interaction with paper will move them along the "z" axis, and
If you think with the idea that there are little pieces of paper inside your phone moving up and down, there is only so far that they can go (5-9mm in most cases). Like so:

[image: The z]

At 03:40 in the video, he states that "paper is generally presented square to the user". That means that the elements are always shown perpendicular, at a 90 degree angle to the surface of the screen. No paper flips (since it would be impossible if the paper was actually "inside" the phone), and usually only soft animations showing the paper turning slightly (usually to indicate the end of a scrollable piece of paper).

And now to answer your question.

Since there actually isn't real paper in your device, and it definitely does not move along a physical "z" axis, how would you be able to create the effect that the object is being moved up or down?

There are two main ways, the first is shadow. With shadows underneath your element, it gives the appearance of it being higher than the surface below, or closer to you than the object behind it. It gives it depth by using shadows. But in actuality, the pixels are all at the same height, and there is no actual physical z axis.

[image]

But, if you only used shadow to illustrate the z axis, it wouldn't feel right. If you increased the shadow underneath the piece of paper, it would fail to communicate that it was getting closer to you. In fact, it would just look like the surface behind it was falling away, but the paper was staying in the exact same place, and the same distance from you.

The second method that is used to correctly illustrate that paper is getting closer to you, is by resizing.

Back to the paper on your desk, if you look at it directly from above, and moved it up towards you, you could see that the paper appeared to grow, the closer it got. It would look bigger. In the below illustration, you see that the object has grown both along the x and y axis, (but only appears to have gotten closer to you, not physically larger in size).

[image]

That's seeing depth by reference to the relative sizes of the objects you are seeing. Objects closer to you appear larger, while objects further away seem smaller, regardless of their actual size.

---

To animate the effect of paper coming closer to you, Material uses these two methods of the way you perceive depth. Shadow and relative size. It increases the size of the paper slightly, both height and width, while creating a shadow beneath it.

So when he says:

> Now why is this asymmetry important ? Well it helps the user understand the difference between something that’s resizing and staying in that place, and something that’s moving within z. If I move within z, that’s kind of the same as symmetric scale, as you get closer is growing in both aspects at the same rate. By doing re-sizes asymmetrically, we’re letting the user know OK, that content is actually staying up at the same z level. The movement is a different signal to them.

Just like here:

[image]

The square looks like it grew, because the x and y are larger, but the shadow beneath is the same. It hasn't moved along the z axis.

That is what he means. If you resize paper on both the x and y axis (wider and taller) simultaneously, it could be confusing, making the paper appear to be coming closer to you, instead of just resizing. To remove the possible confusion, and make the two (resizing and moving along the z) very clear, he suggests resizing asymmetrically, meaning resize the x or the y instead of both, or resize them one before the other if both need to expand.

It's just their way of delineating the two, and presenting a nicer UX.

All images and reference data taken from the Google Design site, article ["What is Material?"](https://design.google.com/resources/#material-design-guidelines) section on ["Elevation and Shadows"](https://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#).

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Now, I understand.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help @vul18. Don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted" if it works for you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. I would also suggest doing the same with the previous questions you've posted, if they have been answered correctly.

Comment: Sorry. Could I also ask that it says "Material is solid. Input events cannot pass through material." Which does "solid" refer to—#1 or #2 ?
#1 Material is soild, not having the form of a gas or liquid, so it cannot be passed through.
#2 Material is soild, not hollow, so it cannot be passed through.
Thank you.

Comment: @vul18, It would be definition #1. Material takes the properties of physical objects, matter in the form of solids. "Cannot be passed through", like if you touched a piece of paper, as opposed to touching water, where your finger *can* pass through.